# Access values from dynamic array via another function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that sets bunch of `setTimeout` functions. All functions are added to Array `funcs`; nevertheless, when I try to stop them using `stopplay().clearTimeout` the array has no values.

How to access those functions and `clearTimeout` on them?

```
var funcs = new Array();    

function playWithDelay(){   
    for (var i = 0; i < PlayDatesArray.length; i++) { 
        funcs[i] = createfunc(i); 
    } 

    for (var j = 0; j < PlayDatesArray.length; j++) { 
        funcs[j]();
    } 
}

function createfunc(i) { 
    return function() {        
        setTimeout(function(){            
        //my function
      }, i*1500);        
    }; 
}

function stopplay(){    
    alert(this.funcs.count);
    for (var i = 0; i< funcs.count; i++){ 
        //things I tried
        var tmpFunction = funcs[i]; 
        //funcs[i].splice(i, 1);
        clearTimeout(tmpFunction);
        clearTimeout(funcs[i]);
        funcs[i]=tmpFunction;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clearTimeout` takes the id returned by `setTimeout`, not a reference to the function itself.

So what you want is (in ES5 code)

```
var timeouts = [];

function createfunc(i) { 
  return function() {        
      return setTimeout(function(){            
      //my function
    }, i*1500);        
  }; 
}

// code to create the functions
function playWithDelay(){   
  for (var i = 0; i < PlayDatesArray.length; i++) { 
    timeouts.push(createfunc(i)());
  }
} 


// code to stop them
function stopplay(){ 
  timeouts.forEach(clearTimeout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing `this.funcs` from `stopplay()`, but funcs is defined (at least, in this example) as a global var.  Depending on what the calling code is that calls stopplay(), `this` is not the same scope as the global scope that `funcs` is created in.

Update  stopplay, changing `this.funcs.count` to `funcs` to see if that is alerted with the array you created above.

Also, are you sure your funcs Array has `count`?  I would try using `length` instead.

```
function stopplay(){    
    alert(funcs.length);
    for (var i = 0; i< funcs.length; i++){ 
    ....
    }    
}
```

EDIT:

You're not saving the return value of setTimeout, so you can't clear the timeout.  Passing clearTimeout with a function doesn't clear the timeout.

You could do something like this:

```
var timers = new Array();


function createfunc(i) { 
   return function() {        
      timers.push( setTimeout(function(){            
        //my function
      }, i*1500)) ;        
   }; 
}


function stopplay(){    
    for (var i = 0; i< timers.length; i++){ 
        clearTimeout(timers[i]);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, got it, messed up with `c#` syntax. But still, clearTimeout is not applied and scheduled functions are executed..

Comment: see my edit, you were not saving the return value from calls to setTimeout.  You need to pass the return value of a setTimeout call to clearTimeout, not the function you first passed to setTimeout.